# store custom size of image immediately taken by camera

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-bitmap

I am taking picture from camera by using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and storing into as database as`BLOB` using cursor. later on i am uploading it over web.

on `onActivityResult` i am getting byte array using `getParcelable` as follows

```
 Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
 byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
 // dumping imageInByte in db , later on i am accessing the same byte array and sending 
 // over network
```

but the issue is , the image size is `144 X  192` which is quite smaller , so is there a 
way to store a custom size image for example `300 X 300`

Answer (score 0):

try [This](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) will help you to take custom size camera picture. this example have small and large size picture capture example